# PHP How can I able to use $this->app just inside class?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP these days. Sorry, if my below query look dumb.

```
 <?php
class A
{
   var $parent;
   var $app;

   function A($parent) {

      $this->parent = $parent;

      if ($parent->isApplication()) {
         $this->app = $parent;
      } else {
         $this->app = $parent->getApplication();
      }
   }


}
?>



<?php
class B extends A

{
    private $app;
    private $cfg;

    public B() {
        $this->app = parent::$app;
        $this->cfg = $this->app->cfg;
    }


}
?>


<?php

class C extends A {
```

function x(){
    new B($this); // calling somewhere in some
    }
    }

```
?>
```

How do I use `$this` inside subclass 'B', I knew that I can use $this inside some function, BUT my intention is to use $app everywhere in that php file, so I am trying to create $app just inside class so that I can use this $app variable anywhere, otherwise I would have used $this inside some function.

**Here is my query:**
How can I able to use `$this->app` just inside class?

**UPDATE:**

```
  <?php
class A
{
   var $parent;
   var $app;

   function Canvas($parent) {

      $this->parent = $parent;

      if ($parent->isApplication()) {
         $this->app = $parent;
      } else {
         $this->app = $parent->getApplication();
      }
   }


}
?>


<?php
class B extends A

{
    private $app;
    private $cfg;

    public Canvas_Access_Approval() {
        $this->app = parent::$app;
        $this->cfg = $this->app->cfg;
    }


}
?>


<?php

class C extends A {

    function x(){
       new B($this);
    }
}

?>
```

**Getting Error as:**   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'B' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Since B extends A, it automatically inherits all of A's properties, you don't need to declare a new `$app` property in B. BTW, you shouldn't use the obsolete `var` declaration, use `public $app` in A.

Comment: WHich line is the error happening on?

Comment: You don't create a constructor with `public B()`, you create it with `public __construct()`. This isn't C.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending class A, so you receive all public / protected properties of this parent. It means:

```
class A {
    public $app = 'test';
}

class B extends A {
    public function get() {
        echo $this->app;
    }
}

new B; // test
```

or (but unnecessarily):

```
class B extends A {
    private $bApp;

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->bApp = $this->app;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please understand my query.. I knew I can able to use $this->app inside some function, but I need to get $app value just inside class, how can I get it? I need $app to use everywhere inside the php file.

Comment: I understand, I'm trying to give you a clue.. PHP telling you, you can't use $this in property declaration, so you have to do this another way. If you can use $this inside a method, then you can set property of class B to property of class A, but why?

Comment: I will make $app in Class A as 'protected'. I wanna use $cfg everywhere inside the php file, so how do I achieve it? I mean, I dont wanna use $cfg = $this->app->config; in every function.

Comment: Inside the php file you mean inside of object? When you inherit properties from parent class, use them directly. As I sad - you can access public and protected properties of parent class(es).

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a class property has to be a literal, it can't refer to any variables or call functions. If you want to compute the default value of a property, you have to do it in the constructor method:

```
class B extends A {
    private $app;
    private $cfg;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->app = parent::$app;
        $this->cfg = $this->app->cfg;
    }
}
```

Note that you can't access class properties as simply `$app` or `$cfg`, they always have to be qualified with `$this->` (when referring to properties of the current object inside the class).

There's not really much point to declaring `$app` in `B`, since it automatically inherits it from `A`, so you can just access it as `$this->app` without the additional declaration.

Comment: I will make $app in Class A as 'protected'. I wanna use $cfg everywhere inside the php file, so how do I achieve it? I mean, I dont wanna use $cfg = $this->app->config; in every function.

Comment: You can't access class properties as normal variables, that's just not how PHP works.

Comment: You have to access it as `$this->cfg` after doing the initialization in the constructor.

Comment: I tried using constructor  function B() and used $app = $this->app inside constructor, but not getting $app value.

Comment: Why are you using OOP if you really want global variables? The whole idea of OOP is to avoid lots of global variables.

Comment: I just updated my code above, please check below 'Update' heading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73920/discussion-between-user3815806-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare $app protected in A, then it will be visible to the class and all subclasses, but not outside of the class.

```
class A {
    protected $app;
}

class B extends A {
    public function demo() {
        $cfg = $this->app->config;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna use $cfg everywhere inside the php file, so how do I achieve it? I mean, I dont wanna use  $cfg = $this->app->config; in every function.